# How to fix errors while creating a new solidity project in Azure Blockcahin Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, visual-studio-code, blockchain

I followed this article by Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/send-transaction.
And I have successfully connected to a consortium member.

But when I try to create a new sample project I encounter these errors.
I have tried my best to fix them

> [Execute command] 
>       [Execute command] - Preparing to download
>       [Execute command] √ Preparing to download
>       [Execute command] - Downloading
>       [Execute command] √ Downloading
>       [Execute command] - Cleaning up temporary files
>       [Execute command] √ Cleaning up temporary files
>       [Execute command] - Setting up box
>       [Execute command] npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
>       npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
>       gyp ERR! build error 
>       gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:196:23)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
>       gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>       gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\kriti\OneDrive\Desktop\trial\node_modules\scrypt
>       gyp ERR! node -v v12.8.0
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
>       gyp ERR! not ok 
>       npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
>       npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\kriti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-09T05_09_56_960Z-debug.log
>       [Execute command] × Setting up box
>       [Execute command] Error: Command failed: npm install
>       npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
>       npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
>       gyp ERR! build error 
>       gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:196:23)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
>       gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>       gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\kriti\OneDrive\Desktop\trial\node_modules\scrypt
>       gyp ERR! node -v v12.8.0
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
>       gyp ERR! not ok 
>       npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
>       npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\kriti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-09T05_09_56_960Z-debug.log
>
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
>           at execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
>           at Object.installBoxDependencies (C:\Users\kriti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\lib\utils\unbox.js:118:1)
>           at Object.setUpBox (C:\Users\kriti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\lib\utils\index.js:62:1)
>           at Object.unbox (C:\Users\kriti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\box.js:58:1)
>       [Execute command] Truffle v5.0.30 (core: 5.0.30)
>       Node v12.8.0
>       [Execute command] Finished running command

Also, all dependencies are installed, though I think they might have the error.

**Edit:
Here is my output, very similar (too big to put in comments):**

```
[Execute command] Setting up box
[Execute command] Error: Command failed: npm install
npm WARN deprecated truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.10: WARNING: This package has been renamed to @truffle/hdwallet-provider.
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\xyz\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
    at Object.installBoxDependencies (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\box\dist\lib\utils\unbox.js:106:1)
    at Object.setUpBox (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\box\dist\lib\utils\index.js:67:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\box\dist\box.js:57:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\box\dist\box.js:4:42)
[Execute command] Truffle v5.0.37 (core: 5.0.37)
Node v10.16.3
[Execute command] Finished running command
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Extremely frustrating when having an error on something so vanilla as creating a basic project.  I have an existing service, consortium and member.  Latest Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 with the prerequisites installed.  Even rebooted to make sure, and verified Node and Python are available from the command prompt and path.

Comment: I gave up but I had my system dualbooted. It worked on Ubuntu 18.04.